# Detect from which page a file was requested

Tags: request, detection

Let's say I load jQuery from a separate domain and host. Can this other host some how detect from which page it was requested from?

**For example:**

Can [www.page-b.com](http://www.page-b.com) somehow know that the link was requested from page [www.page-a.com/subpage](http://www.page-a.com/subpage)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>this page is www.page-A.com/subpage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://page-B.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the HTTP Referrer field of the request. *How* this is done depends highly on the used programming language.
The referer field contains the URL of provenience of the request, which is exactly what you need.

More information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Comment: Just to make shore I understand: So if I for example load my jquery from "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js". Then Google will be able to track all my pages where I have this in the src?

Comment: Basically yes, unless you're doing something _bad_ like removing or faking the HTTP Referrer (you can't do it without a bit of programming of course).

Comment: Cool! Thanks. One more question: If the file allredy have been loaded by the visitor. Will Google then be informed by the request?

Comment: It depends on the caching decisions of the user's browser. Probably the hoster of jQuery (Google in this case) will receive HTTP Requests not to get the file but to ask the time that file was modified (in order for the browser to know whether the cached file is valid or not).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very interesting, that's probebly why companies offers free CDN services ;)